# Java: How to get value from subclass?

Tags: java

my code:

```
public class Cache {
   public getName ()


}
public class EventCache extend Cache {
   public getTN() 

}

public class List {

//here is a function which want to access getTN

}
```

Inside class "List" I have a function which need to access getTN from the subclass EventCache.

I am very new to Java an OOP

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me, what exactly do you mean by _How can I get "getTN" inside class List?_

Comment: Before you can get `TN` you need a reference to the object from which you are planning to get it.

Comment: Create an instance of `Eventcache` and then call the method `getTN`

Comment: What type is getTN? Please post code that compiles

Comment: Please consider reading [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a question of sub class here.For calling method of any class,you need a reference to that class first.

It seems you are interested in subclass.So i would suggest you to put same method in parent and child class and then try to invoke

```
Cache cache = new EventCache();
cache.getTN();
```

If you do this,method from subclass EventCache will be called.
Refer these links to understand more about method overriding in java. [Link1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) [Link2](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/method-overriding-in-java-with-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`EventCache eventCache = new EventCache();
 eventCache.getTN();`

Answer (score 0):

you basically need to instantiate `EvenCache` instead:

```
public class List {

 void doSomething(){
  EventCache e = new EventCache();
  e.getTN();
 }

}
```